# What does it mean when a function has an accent over it? Eg, $\widehat d(x, y) = \min\bigl(d(x, y), 1\bigr)$

Tags: metric-spaces, notation

Take the following function:
$$\widehat d(x, y) = \min\bigl(d(x, y), 1\bigr)$$
What does that mean, is it just a function name? Or does it have a mathematical meaning?

Comment: Yes, it is just a funciton name. Note that there are two metrics here. The metric $d$ and the metric $\hat{d}$ which gets newly introduced. Basically just like writing a_1 and a_2 for different objects. It is just the choice how to differentiate different objects, while simultaniously making clear how the connections are. The notation $\hat{d}$ immediatly significe that $\hat{d}$ is a metric, because $d$ notes usually a metric (distance function), and has something to do with $d$.

Comment: This symbol is named a caret. You will also find it in statistics where it usually means that the value with a caret is an estimator of the value itself: $\hat x$ is an estimator of $x$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just an adjective to change the name slightly.
To write it in mathjax use `$\hat d$`:  $\hat d$.

It's often used for the Fourier transform, but not in this example.